# GTM - Only Click DataLayer elements are available whereas I need a Trigger on a Load Element

Tags: google-tag-manager

In GTM, I'm trying to trigger on page text that's visible after a form is submitted since it does not change to another URL or refresh the page i.e. #bxAddSuccessTitle.  However, the summary of events in GTM only capture the Click elements from the DataLayer.  I've tried DOM, Custom JS variables, Window Load/Page View triggers and nothing populates until I click on the page.

Is there a workaround where I can trigger on something that is visible in the page source, but not necessarily in the datalayer?

`enter code here`[Confirmation Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivAR0.png)
`enter code here`[Confirmation Page Source Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaIRD.png)
`enter code here`[GTM Summary of Events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RszQF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need a visibility trigger, probably with the "observe DOM changes" option active.

This will fire when an element comes into the viewport either by scrolling, when it is unhidden via css or, with the "observe DOM changes", when the element is created/inserted dynamically after a user interaction.

A possible caveat is that the trigger will only fire when the element is visible to the user (unhiding or inserting below the fold will not activate the trigger).

[image: visiblity trigger configuration]

Comment: Perfect - that worked!  I did try an Element Visibility but I think I didn't check Observe DOM changes.  Appreciate the quick response!

Comment: If that helped you can give me a little "reputation" by accepting the answer (clicking the check mark to the left).